# PHP - looking for fread equivalent for type String rather than Resource

Tags: php, arrays, xml-parsing

Is there an existing function which can be implemented the same way as fread but for a string?

for example.

```
    while($string = str_read($huge_string, 500)) {

        echo strlen($string); // 500
    }
```

My current code looks like this.

```
    $length = 8192;

    $array  = str_split($xml, $length);

    while($string = array_shift($array)){

        if (! xml_parse($parser, $string, false))
        {
            return xml_error_string(xml_get_error_code($parser));
        }
    }
    xml_parse($parser, '', true);
    xml_parser_free($parser);
```

Is this the most efficient way of doing this or can it be improved to offer better performance ?

would using a $length of int_get('memory_limit'); be better as it will use less iterations ?

Comment: What is it that you want to achieve?

Comment: ...i believe you're looking for substr http://php.net/substr - or if you want to be able to continiously call this function to get the next 500 bytes, you might want a generator function - http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php - like the xrange example :D xrange($huge_string,PHP_INT_MAX,500);

Comment: generators look, interesting. ill have to read more into that. I shall make an edit,  i try to keep my questions as general as possible so someone else might benefit from it.

Comment: @tvgemert i have made an edit